# Subscript not distinguished enough

Tags: formatting, subscripts

Hi i am using latex to write one paper and i am writing  trying to write $\partial q_k$ but as you can see in the screenshot the k subscript is not distinguished from the letter q. Is this normal? Can i make k a little more distinguished from the letter q so that it looks like a subscript of q .The code that i am using is as follows:

```
\begin{align}
\partial q_k
\end{align}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community. It is very important to put a complete compilable code starting from `\documentclass` to....`\end{document}` with all the packages to understood well the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use (in function of your tastes) `\scriptscriptstyle` like the example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
$\partial q_{k}$ (normal form).

$\partial q_{\scriptscriptstyle k}$ (more more little subscript).
\end{document}
```